# No completion suggestion for inet_aton() in VS Code

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-code

I'm diving into what one could call baby's first network programming right now.
Unfortunately, my VS Code setup (default install + Microsoft's C/C++ extension) can't seem to find one specific function, namely inet_aton().
I have the following includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

and in my code I use the function like this:

```
if (inet_aton (argv [1], &sin.sin_addr) == -1) {...
```

I get suggestion for various other inet_xtoy() functions, just not aton.
The code compiles without problems, so that function is defined somewhere in those includes, but the completion won't pick it up.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.10 right now, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should notify the creator of this specific extension, but you can find the definition for this function [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton). And I recommend you to read it as it says "inet_aton() returns nonzero if the address is valid, zero if not." and as you're checking for "== -1" I'm not sure what your expectation is.

Comment: The creator of the C/C++ extension is Microsoft itself... so I guess I'll just accept it for the time being. Thanks for catching that error. The code was already given to me like that by my instructors. I always check, what the return values are for a specific function when I write my own code, but didn't think of doing so in this case.